# AWS OSGI Disable org.apache.http.wire log

Tags: osgi, aws-sdk

I am using aws osgi sdk , and i need to know how to disable the DEBUG org.apache.http.wire log, is there any log properties and where should i need to add this properties

i have add this property in runtime log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG, but no effect

can any one tell how to disable the http log.